# Error when installing a Shopware 6 app via composer

Tags: shopware6

This is a follow up of [How to install a Shopware 6 app in a composer-managed installation and deploy process?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76268880/how-to-install-a-shopware-6-app-in-a-composer-managed-installation-and-deploy-pr#comment135198981_76269536) - since the original question it became possible to install apps via composer which is great!

But I am getting an error:

```
composer require store.shopware.com/swagcustomnotification # works now

$ bin/console app:refresh

 1 apps will be installed, 0 apps will be updated and 0 apps will be deleted.
Do you want to continue? (yes/no) [yes]:
 > y

                                                                                                                        
 [ERROR] The app "SwagCustomNotification" is invalid:                                                                   
                                                                                                                        
         The technical app name "SwagCustomNotification" in the "manifest.xml" and the folder name must be equal.
```

The folder is `vendor/store.shopware.com/swagcustomnotification` so the error message is correct.

How to fix this?

I am on Shopware 6.5.2.1

EDIT: mainfest.xml:

`<name>SwagCustomNotification</name>`

So this differs of course from the lower case folder name in the `vendor/`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was told via Twitter that [this is a bug which is fixed in trunk](https://github.com/shopware/platform/commit/756cb788d83c5d58dcc080d083f706b6c7944745) / probably released in the next Shopware 6.5 version

The correct issue is https://issues.shopware.com/issues/NEXT-29065

Answer (score 0):

From briefly looking through some documentation, though I am not familiar with shopware. From my understanding it has a directory structure that is required to identify Apps. Therefore you must place your App file into the `custom/apps` directory. This looks to be a necessary for the app-system but that directory will not be created automatically. If you update your shopware installation from a version that did not include the app system.

Follow the link below for more examples and details.

https://issues.shopware.com/issues/NEXT-15704

Comment: Thanks for trying to tacle this even without Shopware knowledge :-) Actually it is a very Shopware specific question, I think I 'd better remove the composer tag :-) It's not in an update - we started with Shopware 6.5 in that project. And the composer support for such App system apps is super new.

Comment: then reduce the composer version. No one said you had to run on it. Run on the most stable version of composer validated with the shopware version. Glad to help if you want to bump ideas off me. I have had the same setup for years (not with shopware) but forge etc... until we moved to PaaS

Comment: To be honest cat the manifest.xml and the path in the json file and compare. That should tell you right away.

Comment: re1) I am not talking about the composer version, I am talking about the fact that apps can be installed via composer. re2) I will check the manifest and update my question